# ¿Que es realmente un argumento nombrado en python?

Tags: python

Antes de establecer definitivamente la pregunta me gustaría que se tuviese en cuenta la [documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) 4.7.1 <-> 4.7.2 concretamente en el ***Aviso importante***.

En este establecen claramente que cuando los argumentos son nombrados y a la vez son mutables, estos mantendrán sus valores entre llamadas a la función, pues la pregunta es, entonces:

**¿Por qué?**

¿Por qué mantendrían estos sus valores, si se supone que todas las variables empleadas en una función se destruyen una vez concluida esta?.

Llegue a suponer que cuando se invoca una función con argumentos nombrados (sin enviarle argumentos en su lugar claro) estas variables se declaran globalmente, y, a menos que lo hagan pero que sean inaccesibles, esto no es cierto...

Comment: El link que pusiste lleva a una sección de la documentación que no creo que sea la que tenías en mente: #arbitrary-argument-lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estás liando algunos conceptos. La advertencia de la documentación no se refiere a valores pasados por nombre, sino a parámetros con *valores por defecto*. Copio el párrafo relevante:

> **Advertencia importante:** El valor por omisión es evaluado solo una vez. Existe una diferencia cuando el valor por omisión es un objeto mutable como una lista, diccionario, o instancia de la mayoría de las clases.

Y de hecho seguidamente te pone un ejemplo:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

Para que entiendas qué ocurre aquí, basta decir que el código anterior equivale en comportamiento a este otro:

```
valor_defecto = []
def f(a, L=valor_defecto):
  L.append(a)
  return L
```

En esta segunda forma se ve claramente que hay un objeto externo a la función, que es una lista vacía. El valor por defecto del parámetro `L` se establece para que sea esa lista externa. Y esa lista estará vacía la primera vez que invoques a la función. Pero ya que la función modifica la lista, añadiendo un elemento, a la vuelta de la función esa lista global tendrá un elemento más:

```
>>> f(3)
[3]
>>> valor_defecto
[3]
>>> f(1)
[3, 1]
>>> valor_defecto
[3, 1]
```

La lista va creciendo, lo que tiene lógica porque es global, y porque el parámetro `L`, cuando no le damos otro valor, está apuntando a esa variable global externa.

La sorpresa es que lo mismo ocurre cuando lo declaras así:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

Y esto es sorprendente sencillamente porque cabe esperar que la asignación `L=[]` creara una lista vacía cada vez que llames a la función, pero no es así. La lista vacía se crea *antes* de que la función se llame, y es externa a la misma, como en el segundo ejemplo, sólo que anónima. Es decir, tu intuicion de que era "global" es básicamente correcta. Pero no la variable `L`, que es interna a la función y muere cuando la función termina, sino la lista con que se incializa `L` si no le pasas otra. Es siempre la misma lista que existe fuera de la función.

Si quieres que la función realmente use una lista vacía *nueva* cada vez que la llamas sin argumentos, la forma correcta sería:

```
def f(a, L=None):
  if L is None:
     L = []
  L.append(a)
  return L
```

Y ahora sí no hay sorpresas:

```
>>> f(3)
[3]
>>> f(1)
[1]
```

### Nota sobre mutabilidad

¿Por qué la advertencia de la documentación menciona expresamente la mutabilidad?

Ocurre que en Python todas las variables son en realidad *referencias* a objetos. Esto vale también para los parámetros de las funciones (se copia al parámetro una referencia al objeto que se está pasando como argumento). Y también para parámetros con valores por defecto (se inicializan con referencias a objetos que son los valores por defecto).

La advertencia que dice "*El valor por omisión es evaluado sólo una vez*" es válida para cualquier tipo de datos Python, sólo que *es conflictiva* si el tipo es mutable. Y la razón es simple. Ya que la función está recibiendo en realidad una referencia a un objeto externo, si desde dentro se usa esa referencia para *mutar* el objeto, esa mutación quedará almacenada en el objeto de forma permanente.

Mutar el objeto consiste en usar alguno de sus métodos para cambiarlo. Por ejemplo si `L` es una lista, usar `L.append()` modifica el objeto al que `L` apunta. O también usar `L[0] = 3` lo modificaría.

En cambio asignar un nuevo valor, no es mutar el objeto. Es decir, si dentro de la función hacemos `L = [1,2,3]`, eso no ha mutado el objeto externo. Lo que ha ocurrido es simplemente que la referencia `L` ha dejado de apuntar a ese objeto externo, para pasar a apuntar a una lista recién creada. El objeto externo sigue con su valor original.

Si el dato que pasamos como valor por defecto a `L` no es mutable (por ejemplo un entero), no hay posibilidad de que observemos los misteriosos efectos secundarios de mutar el objeto. Un entero no es mutable porque no tiene métodos para cambiarlo. Por ejemplo, no existe un hipotético `int.increment()` que cambie un 1 por un 2. Y si en cambio la función hace algo como `L=L+1` (siendo `L` un entero, por ejemplo con el valor 1), tampoco se estaría mutando nada por lo antes explicado, sólo se estaría cambiando la referencia que apuntaba a un 1 para que apunte a un 2.

#### Otro ejemplo

Una clase creada por tí también es mutable, porque una vez tienes una referencia a un objeto (digamos `x`) puedes hacerle cosas como `x.atributo=valor`. Así que en funciones que reciban como parámetro por defecto una instancia de una clase, ocurrirá lo mismo que con listas o diccionarios. Si la función modifica atributos de ese objeto, las modificaciones son persistentes entre llamadas:

```
class Clase:
  def __init__(self):
    self.v = 0

def cuidado(obj=Clase()):
  obj.v = obj.v + 1
  print(obj.v)
```

La creación del objeto `Clase()` que se asigna como valor por defecto ocurre una sola vez, y no en cada llamada.

```
>>> cuidado()
1
>>> cuidado()
2
>>> cuidado()
3
```

Naturalmente no hay problemas si le pasas tú un valor en vez de usar el valor por defecto:

```
>>> cuidado(Clase())
1
>>> cuidado(Clase())
1
>>> cuidado(Clase()
1
```

Comment: La respuesta es _casi_ perfecta, a la explicación le añadiría que esto ocurre solo cuando el valor por defecto es un objeto mutable.  Quizás hasta sea buena idea citar el texto de [la advertencia](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values), que es bastante claro y está no solo mal interpretado por el AP, sino mal copiado en la pregunta.

Comment: @jachguate Gracias por el comentario. He extendido un poco la respuesta, pero el tema es farragoso y temo que la explicación haya oscurecido más el asunto. Espero que no sea así!

Comment: +1, yo he quedado convencido :). Un saludo.

Comment: @abulafia ciertamente, muy buena respuesta, por cierto, gracias por recomendarme la documentacion, sin duda es la mejor fuente de infomacion al respecto.